# How to remove this bracket

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex bath, but there's an extra bracket in the references. I've tried some methods, but it doesn't work,

```
\usepackage[style=bath,backend=biber,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\assignrefcontextentries[]{*}
```

```
@article{plumbEddyFluxesConserved1979,
  title = {Eddy {{Fluxes}} of {{Conserved Quantities}} by {{Small}}-{{Amplitude Waves}}},
  author = {Plumb, R. A.},
  date = {1979-09-01},
  journaltitle = {Journal of the Atmospheric Sciences},
  shortjournal = {J. Atmos. Sci.},
  volume = {36},
  pages = {1699-1704},
  publisher = {{American Meteorological Society}},
  issn = {0022-4928},
  doi = {10.1175/1520-0469(1979)036<1699:EFOCQB>2.0.CO;2},
  langid = {english},
  number = {9}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a small oversight in `biblatex-bath` that you should report to its developer (e.g. at https://github.com/alex-ball/bathbib/issues). (*Edit* reported at https://github.com/alex-ball/bathbib/issues/9.)

When I try to build an MWE from your entry I get a slightly different result, namely

[image: Plumb, R.A., 1979. Eddy fluxes of conserved quantities by small-amplitude waves. Journal of the atmospheric sciences [Online], 36(9) (), 1 September, pp.1699–1704. Available from: https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0469(1979)036<1699:EFOCQB>2.0.CO;2.]

There is a '1 September' after the empty pair of brackets.

Here is a temporary way to avoid this empty pair while you wait for a fix by the maintainer of the style.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=bath,backend=biber,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\assignrefcontextentries[]{*}

  \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iffieldundef{issue}}
      and
      test {\iffieldundef{month}}
    }{}{%
      \ifboolexpr{(
        test {\iffieldundef{volume}}
        and
        test {\iffieldundef{number}}
        ) and
        test {\iffieldundef{eid}}
      }{%
        \newunit
        \printfield{issue}%
      }{%
        \printfield[parens]{issue}%
      }
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \printdate
    }%
    \newunit
  }%

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{plumb,
  title        = {Eddy Fluxes of Conserved Quantities by Small-Amplitude Waves},
  author       = {Plumb, R. A.},
  date         = {1979-09-01},
  journaltitle = {Journal of the Atmospheric Sciences},
  volume       = {36},
  number       = {9},
  pages        = {1699-1704},
  doi          = {10.1175/1520-0469(1979)036<1699:EFOCQB>2.0.CO;2},
  langid       = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,plumb}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Plumb, R.A., 1979. Eddy fluxes of conserved quantities by small-amplitude waves. Journal of the atmospheric sciences [Online], 36(9), 1 September, pp.1699–1704. Available from: https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0469(1979)036<1699:EFOCQB>2.0.CO;2.]

Comment: Sir, you're great for `biblatex`....Salute to you....

Comment: Great thanks, It works. This looks like a bug...